# SVG renders incorrectly

Tags: svg

I have done this on CodePen and it works but when I see it on a browser it doesn't render correctly. It stays on the original size (145, 90) but the svg seems to be scaling.
Once I change the viewbox property in the browser to something else manually and then back to "0 0 145 90" it works as I want it to.

```html
    <svg data-v-1d986156="" viewbox="0 0 145 90">
      <g data-v-1d986156="">
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="end" x="13" y="71" style="font-size: 6px; fill: rgb(0, 51, 102);">7</text>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="end" x="13" y="61" style="font-size: 6px; fill: rgb(0, 51, 102);">14</text>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="end" x="13" y="51" style="font-size: 6px; fill: rgb(0, 51, 102);">21</text>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="end" x="13" y="41" style="font-size: 6px; fill: rgb(0, 51, 102);">28</text>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="end" x="13" y="31" style="font-size: 6px; fill: rgb(0, 51, 102);">35</text>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="end" x="13" y="21" style="font-size: 6px; fill: rgb(0, 51, 102);">42</text>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="end" x="13" y="11" style="font-size: 6px; fill: rgb(0, 51, 102);">49</text>
        <line data-v-1d986156="" x1="15" y1="69" x2="145" y2="69" stroke="#003366" stroke-width="0.2"></line>
        <line data-v-1d986156="" x1="15" y1="59" x2="145" y2="59" stroke="#003366" stroke-width="0.2"></line>
        <line data-v-1d986156="" x1="15" y1="49" x2="145" y2="49" stroke="#003366" stroke-width="0.2"></line>
        <line data-v-1d986156="" x1="15" y1="39" x2="145" y2="39" stroke="#003366" stroke-width="0.2"></line>
        <line data-v-1d986156="" x1="15" y1="29" x2="145" y2="29" stroke="#003366" stroke-width="0.2"></line>
        <line data-v-1d986156="" x1="15" y1="19" x2="145" y2="19" stroke="#003366" stroke-width="0.2"></line>
        <line data-v-1d986156="" x1="15" y1="9" x2="145" y2="9" stroke="#003366" stroke-width="0.2"></line>
      </g>
      <line data-v-1d986156="" x1="0" y1="79" x2="145" y2="79" stroke="#003366"></line>
      <g data-v-1d986156="">
        <rect data-v-1d986156="" fill="#49e5a6" id="outstanding" x="22.5" y="53" width="25" height="25.57"></rect>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="middle" x="35" y="88" class="percent" style="font: 8px serif;">15.8%</text>
      </g>
      <g data-v-1d986156="">
        <rect data-v-1d986156="" fill="#00b9c1" id="good" x="52.5" y="13.3" width="25" height="65.34"></rect>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="middle" x="65" y="88" class="percent" style="font: 8px serif;">40.4%</text>
      </g>
      <g data-v-1d986156="">
        <rect data-v-1d986156="" fill="#e76d93" id="requires_improvement" x="82.5" y="21.8" width="25" height="56.82"></rect>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="middle" x="95" y="88" class="percent" style="font: 8px serif;">35.1%</text>
      </g>
      <g data-v-1d986156="">
        <rect data-v-1d986156="" fill="#ffcb4b" id="inadequate" x="112.5" y="64.4" width="25" height="14.2"></rect>
        <text data-v-1d986156="" text-anchor="middle" x="125" y="88" class="percent" style="font: 8px serif;">8.8%</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

- Images:

[image: Image of the svg on the browser]

[image: Image of the svg on the browser]

[image: Image of the svg on codepen]

Comment: The 300 x 150 suggests you've not defined the container size properly, that's the fallback if a replaced element can't establish its size. You've not provided any details of the container though.

Comment: try `viewBox` instead of `viewbox`